# Arduino uno with Visual Studio 2008

Tags: vb.net, arduino

I have a visual studio program to send instruction to Arduino uno. But when I try to compile I see the following error.

```
"WithEvents variable 'SerialPort1' implicitly defines   >'_SerialPort1', which conflicts with a member of the same name in class 'Form1'.   C:\Users\*****\Desktop\WindowsApplication1\WindowsApplication1\Form1.Designer.vb    77
"
```

Can any one please help me to solve this problem?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.IO.Ports
Imports System.Threading

Public Class Form1
    Shared _continue As Boolean
    Shared _serialPort1 As SerialPort


    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        SerialPort1.Close()
        SerialPort1.PortName = "com31" 'change com port to match your Arduino port
        SerialPort1.BaudRate = 9600
        SerialPort1.DataBits = 8
        SerialPort1.Parity = Parity.None
        SerialPort1.StopBits = StopBits.One
        SerialPort1.Handshake = Handshake.None
        SerialPort1.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.Default 'very important!
    End Sub



    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        SerialPort1.Open()
        SerialPort1.Write("1")
        SerialPort1.Close()
    End Sub


    Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        SerialPort1.Open()
        SerialPort1.Write("0")
        SerialPort1.Close()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the variable name in the below line is conflicting.

```
Shared _serialPort1 As SerialPort
```

Try renaming the variable.